# Flask mega tutorial part 5 error

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

Im going through the Microblog tutorial for Flask designed by Miguel.

I made it to part 4 without any issues. Everything ran in the end of part 4.

I started having issues in part 5. After a couple of tries and trying to troubleshoot with the comments in the page, I was not able to finish the exercise.

Thinking it was me, I deleted all of my project and replaced them with the zip downloadable in the page for the exercise. I still get the same error, so the problem is not the code itself.

I get the following error when running views.py:

[Link to image on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKa3A.jpg) (couldn't post it here due to not having enough reputation)

Here are the libraries I have installed:

[Link to image on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uSeU.jpg) (couldn't post it here due to not having enough reputation)

My setup:

- I am using Pycharm to run the files. This machine runs Windows and I found that Pycharm is the most efficient way to run things without dealing with issues with the cmd line.
- Python 3.4
- virtualenv created by Pycharm
- the code can be found on github: github.com/pdgonzalez872/microblog

Potential cause of the problem:

- The problem may be with the path that I have set up (but why did it work until part 4?)
- The code itself (maybe something was updated in flask/other libraries since the post?)

Comment: Rather than pasting an image of the error text, try  copy-pasting the error text itself. 1) you don't need rep to do that, and 2) it makes it much easier for the rest of us to read it.

Comment: will do that from now on @Robᵩ, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`views.py` isn't meant to be launched separately, there is `run.py` file to start the project.

Also, it uses relative imports (those with dots before module names), which don't work when you use them in a script passed to the interpreter and used as **main**. Sorry, I can't explain it well, but maybe you will be interested in those links:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: so views.py could fail when running by itself but it may not cause the whole app to fail? Interesting! The reason I ran the scripts separately was to see if there were any syntax issues (I typed the code instead of copy/paste). They always worked, except the views.py - Will continue to try it out! Thank you. (I can't upvote you due to lack of reputation... I would though!)

Comment: @pdgonzalez782, you are welcome. Also, if you are using Pycharm, it shoud highlight all syntax errors for you.